# How do i create a live form which can display whatever i fill side by side in a design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have a form for which has fields like card no ,card holders name,expiry date and stuff i want something like whenever i am filling the form it should be displayed side by side before storing it to database ,any help?

Answer (score 1):

Bind it to  a jQuery keyup event

```
<form>
  Card No:</br>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<p id="display">
</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(":number").keyup(function () { 
$("#display").text($(":number").val());
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for a while until i needed to update using the same form which already has data filled to it so keyup function wont work ? How do i take the value which is already there in the form and display somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really easy solution in vanilla js;

```js
let input = document.getElementById('in');
input.onkeyup = () => {
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```html
<input id='in' type='text'>

<p id='p'></p>
```

Comment: Thanks i used jQuery for that and it all works fine now

Comment: Please leave an upvote if it helped. You can also mark it as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks